# JPA achive of scalability - mapping with entity relationships vs. mapping with IDs (int, longs)

Tags: database-design, jpa

In order to achieve better scalability in relational database, do you think that sometimes it's better to avoid reference key constraints (exposed via JPA's ORM annotations) via describing them just with collection of ID's.

For example, next relation between two entities

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "ContactGroup_User", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_NAME_GROUP_PK), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_NAME_USER_PK)
)
private List<User> users;
```

could be described also :

```
private List<Long> userIds;
```

This is in order in some day to scale your (vertical scaling for example) database and no references keys and constraints to prevent you in some way and make you. And when user's data is required, this could be done with associated JPA queries.

All related comments could be useful!

Thanks,
Simeon